# How find this $I_{n}=\int_{-1}^{1}\arccos{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}x^{2k-1}\right)}dx$

Tags: integration

Find this value
$$I_{n}=\int_{-1}^{1}\arccos{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}x^{2k-1}\right)}dx=\pi?$$

My try: since
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}x^{2k-1}=\dfrac{x(1-(-x^2)^{n})}{1+x^2}$$
so
$$I_{n}=\int_{-1}^{1}\arccos{\left(\dfrac{x(1-(-x^2)^{n})}{1+x^2}\right)}dx$$
then I can't work.Thank you very much !

Comment: Have you tried stupidly integrating by parts? What shows up? When $n=1$ integration by parts gives you $\pi$ as the answer in one step. (I don't have paper, I can't try it myself.)

Comment: Better to write your term as $(-1)^nx^{2n}$.  You could start with Patrick's suggestion and try induction; you might want to split that into two cases -- n even, n odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle\phi(x)=\cos^{-1}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^kx^{2k+1}\right)$. Notice that $\phi(-x)+\phi(x)=\pi$.

We are looking for
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1(\phi(x)+\phi(-x))\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^1\pi\,\mathrm{d}x\\[9pt]
&=\pi
\end{align}
$$
We could have used any odd function that maps $[-1,1]\mapsto[-1,1]$ in place of the sum we used here and get the same answer.